# How can I flash_erase mtd0?

Tags: permissions, partition, flash-memory

I am trying to find a way to `nandwrite` my mtd0 partition which contains my u-boot environment. When I try to `flash_eraseall /dev/mtd0` though I get:

> flash_eraseall: /dev/mtd0: Permission denied

Is there any way I can get permission to do this? After doing some reading I get the suspicion that I would have to modify and recompile my Kernel. I am trying to find a way to work around that though.

Comment: when I run `flash_eraseall --version`, I get "flash_eraseall has been replaced by `flash_erase <mtddev> 0 0`; please use it.."

Answer (score 1):

2 things to check.

1. Is the device, `/dev/mtd0` mounted?

   You can confirm this using the `mount` command. A entry will show that it's mounted, and the flash tool may not be able to erase the device while mounted.

   #### Example

   ```
   $ mount
   /dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw)
   proc on /proc type proc (rw)
   sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
   devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
   tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
   /dev/sda5 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
   /dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_home on /home type ext4 (rw)
   ```

   If there is an entry here, then you can unmount it using the command, `umount`.

   #### Example

   ```
   $ sudo umount /dev/mtd0
   ```

   Then try running the erase command.
2. Can you flash erase a device as a regular user?

   Often regular users are not permitted to perform such potentially dangerous operations, so typically you'll need to become root to do them. Try your command like so.

   #### Example

   ```
   $ sudo flash_eraseall /dev/mtd0
   ```