# flash_erase & nandwrite seem to work, but uname -a shows the same kernel version

Tags: embedded, flash-memory, write

I've seen this question:

[How can I flash_erase mtd0?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99476/how-can-i-flash-erase-mtd0/99503#99503?newreg=0357b8bfa1d84293865a09fae41ef35a)

I have a similar problem with my mini2440. When I use

```
flash_erase /dev/mtd2 0 0
```

and then

```
nandwrite -p -N /dev/mtd2 uImage-mini2440
```

Everything seems fine, but when I reboot the version of the kernel is exactly the same as it was (shown with `uname -a`)

Why don't `flash_erase` and `nadwrite` work?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. The command was working correctly. I had used a wrong version of the kernel.
Thanks