# Cannot access nand or emmc partition from linux

Tags: linux, partition, busybox, flash-memory

I have a i.mx6 based board running using buildroot and linux.
This board have two storages nand and emmc. The nand had full rootfs and kernel on itself. I am now booting from SD card.
From the boot logs I can see the nand and emmc partition getting detected

```
[    3.440294] 5 ofpart partitions found on MTD device gpmi-nand
[    3.446084] Creating 5 MTD partitions on "gpmi-nand":
[    3.451148] 0x000000000000-0x000000200000 : "boot"
[    3.456431] 0x000000200000-0x000000500000 : "scratch"
[    3.461632] 0x000000500000-0x000000b00000 : "kernel"
[    3.467091] 0x000000b00000-0x000001100000 : "recovery"
[    3.472521] 0x000001100000-0x000010000000 : "rootfs"
[    3.481312] gpmi-nand 112000.gpmi-nand: driver registered.
```

and emmc

```
[    4.318175]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
```

I can see the devices for nand are registered and shown in `/dev/mtd*`.
Now I am using `nand and mmc-utils` provided by buildroot.
I am trying to write some data on nand like this.Writing a simple text file test.txt,

```
#nandwrite -b 1 -n /dev/mtd0 -p /test.txt
```

[See full error log on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/raw/FZdk2hUT)

```
#flash_erase /dev/mtd0

flash_erase: error!: no start erase block specified
flash_erase: error!: no erase block count specified
flash_erase: error!: Try `--help' for more information
```

Can anyone tell the correct way/steps to be followed in case of nand, sd interaction. I followed this thread

[StackExchange: how-can-i-flash-erase-mtd0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99476/how-can-i-flash-erase-mtd0)

Similarly I am not able to flash, or do anything with emmc.

```
#mmc status get /dev/mmcblk0
SEND_STATUS response: 0x00000900
```

This looks ok, but how to really write or erase mmc? There are many commands associted with mmc , and not know which should I use,

[mmc-utils manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/mmc-utils/mmc.1.en.html)

Some more checks

```
# mtdinfo 
Count of MTD devices: 5
Present MTD devices: mtd0, mtd1, mtd2, mtd3, mtd4
Sysfs interface supported: yes
# mtd
mtd_debug mtdev-test mtdev2tuio mtdinfo
# mtdev
mtdev-test mtdev2tuio
# mtdev-test 
Usage: mtdev <device>
# mtdev-test /dev/mtd0
error: could not grab the device
```

I am guessing that maybe nand devices are locked, but how to check that?

What are the prerequisites/steps to access nand?